# Documentação no inicio de um projeto trabalhando sozinho

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, gerenciamento-de-projetos, projeto-de-software

Estudando sobre análise e projeto orientados a objetos encontrei vários tipos de documentos que são construidos antes de qualquer código ser desenvolvido. Entre esses documentos estão user stories, casos de uso e diversos diagramas UML. Tudo isso, entretanto, é sempre discutido no contexto de uma equipe de desenvolvimento.

Uma coisa que fica clara é que esses documentos existem para que seja possível existir uma melhor comunicação entre os membros da equipe, ou seja, a ideia é aprimorar a comunicação. Além disso, alguns documentos são extremamente formais e existem por regras da empresa na qual o projeto está sendo desenvolvido.

Eu, entretanto, trabalho sozinho, e sempre fiquei em dúvida com relação a quais documentos realmente são **necessários** ao iniciar um projeto. Costumo usar basicamente user stories, casos de uso e o diagrama de classes, mas já ouvi falar que até o diagrama de classes poderia ser dispensado em casos como esse.

Nesse caso, ao começar um *novo* projeto trabalhando sozinho, quais documentos são realmente indispensáveis pensando não só no inicio do desenvolvimento mas no futuro do projeto?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Como me parece ser este o foco da pergunta, vou falar apenas da documentação da **engenharia** de software e não da documentação de **uso** do software.

Sua observação de que a documentação visa a comunicação na equipe está correta aceitando-se a premissa de que o cliente (ou o representante do cliente) faz parte da equipe. Ou seja: documentação visa comunicação **cliente <-> equipe <-> equipe**.

Há quem escreva documentação visando até mesmo que outras equipes assumam o sistema no futuro e se beneficiem desta documentação.

Mas escrever muita documentação tentando garantir o futuro é uma prática cada vez mais em desuso na nossa indústria. Pois depois de tantas décadas escrevendo toneladas de documentação estamos aprendendo que ela nunca ajudou muito <sup>[[1](http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/05/DoD_agile)]</sup>.

Estamos tentando trazer para o desenvolvimento de software <sup>[[2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321150783)][[8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0984521402)]</sup> o *Pensamento Lean* <sup>[[3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0743249275)]</sup> que tornou a indústria automotiva japonesa um fabuloso sucesso e que depois disso vem ajudando em diversas áreas de atuação em todo o mundo <sup>[[4](http://www.mckinsey.com/insights/public_sector/applying_lean_production_to_the_public_sector)]</sup>.

Segundo o pensamento Lean, é fundamental eliminar todo o desperdício. Toda atividade que não agrega valor para o cliente precisa ser eliminada. Portanto, segundo esta corrente, **você só deveria escrever os documentos que agregam valor para o cliente**.

Além disso, o segundo princípio do Desenvolvimento Ágil <sup>[[5](http://www.agilemanifesto.org/)]</sup> diz:

> "Valorizamos mais software funcionando do que documentação abrangente."

E o Ágil vem se tornando o padrão da indústria <sup>[[9](http://www.cio.com/article/2383384/agile-development/has-agile-software-development-gone-mainstream-.html)]</sup> em detrimento de outros modelos que exigem muita documentação.

## Como saber se um documento agrega valor?

Perguntas que ajudam a identificar se um documento tem potencial de agregar valor são:

> A quem este documento tem o objetivo de ajudar?
>
> Alguém vai ler este documento?

Se você não pode identificar o beneficiário direto do documento ou tem grandes dúvidas se este documento sequer será lido, é melhor não escrevê-lo; pelo menos não agora.

## Quando vale a pena escrever um documento mesmo que ninguém vá ler depois?

> Escrever ajuda a estruturar as idéias e a fazer descobertas.

Então escrever diagramas de classe, de sequência e casos de uso ajudam a aprofundar o entendimento dos requisitos e a descobrir como resolver o problema.

Mas documentos com este fim não devem ser vistos como documentação do sistema, não precisam ser formais e não devem ser mantidos por mais tempo do que a duração da tarefa de implementar aquela parte específica do software (isso mesmo, jogue no lixo depois de usar).

## Documentação de requisitos de software

Você falou em *user stories* - elas são excelentes para descrever requisitos. O @Luiz Vieira já fez em sua resposta indispensável uma bela descrição delas. O que eu tenho a acrescentar é que elas devem ser jogadas fora tão logo o projeto termine ou mesmo antes assim que a *feature* for entregue. Elas não devem ser vistas como documentação perene do software sob pena de perderem sua flexibilidade e simplicidade indispensáveis para o sucesso na sua utilização.

Em tempo: uma *user story* pode perfeitamente ser acompanhada de documentos adicionais. Por exemplo, uma *user story* que pede um relatório pode ser acompanhada de uma página que simula um exemplo de um relatório.

Uma *user story* também pode ser acompanhada dos seus testes de aceitação, que descrevem como a completude da implementação da história será verificada.

Então embora *user stories* sejam de fato requisitos de software, elas não dispensam necessariamente outros documentos, que só serão adicionados se houver utilidade clara.

## Afinal, trabalhando sozinho quais documentos devo escrever?

Alguns documentos que agregam valor tanto para equipes como em projetos solo são:

- **Visão do projeto:** <sup>[[6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vision_document)][[7](https://www.scrumalliance.org/community/articles/2009/january/the-product-vision)]</sup> qual problema será resolvido e como será resolvido e qual o valor desta solução para o cliente. Isto é muito importante para manter o foco e não se distrair com o que não for prioridade nem desviar o projeto do seu objetivo principal. Este documento é muito curto e o simples ato de escrevê-lo, como eu disse, ajuda a aprofundar o entendimento do problema e da solução.
- **User stories:** <sup>[[10](http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/agile/user-stories)]</sup> Enquanto são escritas, ajudam a entender cada pedaço do problema e a solução desejada. Depois de escritas, ajudam a priorizar os recursos a serem implementados.

Em um projeto Ágil, solo ou em equipe, estes são os documentos formais de vida mais longa. Sendo que o primeiro é o único que nasce bastante completo já no começo do projeto. *User stories* serão escritas ao longo do projeto. Outros documentos serão utilizados para ajudar no desenvolvimento das idéias mas são muito informais e serão dispensados rápidamente.

Demais documentos só devem ser escritos por demanda específica do projeto. Se o cliente fizer questão de pagar não apenas por software funcionando mas também por diagramas de classes e casos de uso, é claro que você terá que fazer. Neste caso, de preferência contrate um estagiário para fazê-los - uma boa parte disso pode inclusive ser gerada automaticamente por várias ferramentas disponíveis por aí <sup>[[11](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657806.aspx)]</sup>.

Comment: Fantástica resposta. Aliás, na minha opinião você acertou em cheio com "[...] uma *user story* que pede um relatório pode ser acompanhada de uma página que simula um exemplo de um relatório.". Afinal, desde a construção das pirâmides já se sabe que protótipos ajudam muito e são certamente mais eficientes em produzir um bom entendimento do que o cliente deseja/precisa do que qualquer documento (seja o cliente um Faraó ou não). :)

Answer (score 12):

A análise e projeto orientados a objetos que você está estudando é apenas um dos assuntos (talvez o mais popular, digamos) dentro da disciplina de Engenharia de Software. Tal como qualquer outra engenharia, o objetivo da disciplina é auxiliar na construção de algo. Porém, nesse caso não são pontes ou circuitos elétricos, e sim sistemas de software.

Eu começo com esse "lembrete" porque as vezes nós nos esquecemos que mesmo que estejamos construindo algo intangível como software, ainda assim utilizamos um processo de engenharia que envolve observação, medição, planejamento e construção. De forma similar, um engenheiro civil ou mecânico, por exemplo, utiliza *[blueprints](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blueprint)* (entre outras ferramentas) para não apenas comunicar decisões de projeto a colegas de trabalho, mas principalmente para formalizar suas próprias decisões de projeto. Afinal, a memória humana tem suas limitações e se você mesmo não escrever o que decidiu hoje pode ser que não se lembre da motivação para tal amanhã ou semana que vem.

A orientação a objetos nada mais é do que uma "forma de pensar" a respeito de como a representação do problema e a execução da solução (pelo computador) devem ser realizadas. Discorrer mais sobre isso seria complicado aqui, até porque o assunto daria uma ou mais perguntas por si só (e, de fato, já há bastante material aqui mesmo no SOPT que pode lhe ajudar). De todas as formas, muitas das ferramentas de documentação que você cita poderiam ser utilizadas com qualquer outra abordagem de engenharia de software, tal como projeto estruturado, orientado a serviços ou mesmo orientado a agentes. Por que? Porque a ideia de seu uso é auxiliar nos objetivos de engenharia (observar, medir, planejar e executar).

No nosso caso (engenharia de software), observar significa entender o problema a ser resolvido (o problema pode ser seu ou de seu cliente), medir significa estimar os recursos necessários (tempo, dinheiro, equipamentos, módulos, e por ai vai), planejar significa literalmente escolher a melhor abordagem de resolução (não apenas quais algorítmos, mas também o que dentro do problema deve ou não ser solucionado, de quais formas, usando quais interações com os usuários, etc). E, por fim, executar significa programar e, principalmente, testar se o seu produto final realmente atende à necessidade originalmente observada.

Considerando essas colocações, a decisão por usar ou não certa ferramenta ou documento depende não apenas do fato de você precisar comunicar decisões a outras pessoas, mas também do seu julgamento a respeito de algo ser útil ou não *naquele escopo* de projeto. Nas discussões sobre RUP x Scrum, por exemplo, é muito comum o dogmatismo (a abordagem XXX é ruim porque é burocrática/simplista, etc, etc, etc). Mas há de se perceber, sem demagogia, que tudo tem sua utilidade. Claro, regras demais que são seguidas cegamente sem propósito só geram dificuldade, e se tornam isso mesmo: burocracia.

Para não me alongar demais, vou encerrar com pequenas discussões sobre cada uma das ferramentas que você citou:

- **Casos de Uso**. A parte fundamental na engenharia de software é o entendimento do problema a ser solucionado. Se um problema não é bem entendido, não importa a qualidade do sistema construído pois ele simplesmente não servirá. É por isso que muito do esforço na engenharia de software é colocado na tão falada análise de requisitos. Trata-se basicamente em entender *muito bem* o que o cliente precisa. Entretanto, sistemas de software são produtos muito menos tangíveis do que pontes, carros ou cadeiras. As vezes os clientes também não sabem descrever os detalhes do que eles desejam. É por isso que essa ferramenta existe. Por meio dela, o engenheiro constroi os cenários (casos) em que as principais funções do sistema a ser construído são utilizadas, como forma de pré-validar o entendimento de que o sistema realmente fará o que é necessário (não importa como, nesse momento). Aliás, o UML é apenas uma linguagem formal (como inglês ou notação musical) que auxilia na comunicação. Como os clientes dos nossos projetos não têm a nossa formação técnica, a comunicação com eles precisa ser a mais simples possível. Não é a toa que os diagramas de caso de uso são praticamente infantis, isto é, usam bolinhas, homenzinhos de palito e setinhas para comunicar esse tipo de informação.
- **Histórias de Usuário**. As histórias de usuário têm exatamente a mesma intenção dos casos de uso: auxiliar no entendimento do problema. Porém elas têm a característica de descrever algo que o usuário faz ou precisa como parte do seu trabalho, primordialmente do *seu ponto de vista* e na forma de sentenças curtas de texto. Diferentemente dos casos de uso, não é o projetista que cria o documento formal e pergunta para o usuário se está correto o entendimento, e sim o contrário. O usuário descreve o que ele faz (conta a sua história) e transmite ao projetista. Essa aparente informalidade (aparente porque você ainda precisa armazenar essas informações para referência futura) é o que torna esse tipo de ferramenta mais atraente para metodologias ágeis (tal como [XP](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_extrema)). Além disso, as histórias não focam tanto (ao menos inicialmente) na existência do sistema, e por isso permitem ao engenheiro explorar junto com o cliente as reais necessidades de uma forma mais isenta. Por que isso é uma potencial vantagem? Porque a comunicação nem sempre é fácil, os usuários podem não saber explicar o que precisam, e as vezes a motivação para automação sequer parte deles (há outros *[stakeholders](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stakeholder)* envolvidos). O mal entendimento das necessidades e da forma como o problema é atualmente tratado faz com que infelizmente seja comum que a implantação de um sistema altere tão drasticamente a rotina dos usuários a ponto de tornar uma tarefa que antes era considerada razoavelmente fácil em algo difícil e até despropositado. E se o usuário não está engajado no uso de um sistema, dificilmente o esforço de desenvolvimento dará o resultado esperado.

> "*Eu vou aqui automatizar esse seu preenchimento manual de orçamento
>   via bloquinho que você leva pra lá e pra cá, ok? Você ainda o
>   preencherá manualmente, só que tela do computador. Muito mais fácil e seguro!
>   Ah, eu te disse que antes de cada orçamento você precisará fazer login
>   com essa senha de 8 dígitos, 2 caracteres especiais e 3 números (que
>   você será obrigado a trocar semanalmente)? Sim, naquele único terminal
>   que fica láááá atrás da loja, há uns 100 metros de onde você geralmente fica.*"

- **Diagrama de Classes**. As duas ferramentas anteriores poderiam ser utilizadas em qualquer abordagem de engenharia de software que você escolher (até mesmo no projeto estruturado). O Diagrama de Classes, porém, é muito mais ligado à abordagem orientada a objetos porque ele literamente descreve as classes que o sistema utilizará para solucionar o problema. Novamente, a UML é apenas a linguagem que formaliza essa descrição. Se você a utiliza, partindo do princípio de que outras pessoas também a aprenderam porque é algo padronizado, fica fácil você eventualmente entregar esse documento para outra pessoa e ela entender rapidamente o que o sistema engloba. O que o sistema faz é mais bem descrito por outro diagrama (o Diagrama de Sequência), já que o Diagrama de Classes não representa a troca de mensagens que o sistema utiliza para executar e solucionar o problema. O Diagrama de Classes representa particularmente o *domínio do problema*. Isto é, quais elementos fazem parte da solução planejada/construída. Por exemplo, se você tem uma classe "Cliente", é porque você representa o cliente dentro do seu sistema e tem algum motivo forte para isso. De certa forma, a construção desse diagrama auxilia o engenheiro no desenvolvimento da solução, porque facilita que ele observe quais entidades precisam ser representadas, que tipo de dados elas precisarão manter e ter uma visão inicial dos comportamentos que elas proverão para a solução do problema. Você não precisaria construí-lo, mas isso é uma boa prática porque ela complementa o entendimento intencionado pelas ferramentas anteriores. Em verdade, equipes bem estabelecidas que usam essas ferramentas da maneira adequada chegam até mesmo a ter uma boa rastreabilidade de requisitos, isto é, saber quais peças elementais do sistema (classes, componentes, arquivos de código, etc) existem para atender quais funcionalidades (requisitos) e vice-versa. Esse tipo de análise facilita um bocado à gestão na decisão de impactos de mudanças, planejamento de prioridades, estimação de esforço, e por ai vai.

Concluindo, eu diria que não há nada que seja realmente necessário (no sentido estrito da palavra) para você iniciar um desenvolvimento sozinho. Porém, é uma boa prática você utilizar algum formalismo para descrever e documentar ao menos o entendimento do problema. Como outros colegas já comentaram, é sabido que o custo de manutenção é consideravelmente mais alto posteriormente, e isso é especialmente complicado caso você perceba apenas tardiamente que construiu algo que era desnecessário ou, pior, que não atende às necessidades. Além do mais, mesmo que você esteja no momento trabalhando sozinho, lembre-se de que essa não é a situação comum: na maioria dos projetos você irá trabalhar com outras pessoas, clientes, artistas/desginers gráficos, etc. Se você for alguém já acostumado a trabalhar com práticas estabelecidas no mercado, isso certamente facilitará que vocÊ consiga novos projetos e se integre com outras equipes.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Vou responder com meu exemplo.

Estou trabalhando em um projeto com 150 tabelas e mais ou menos 2.000 paginas PHP.

Sabemos, na área de "qualidade", que o custo da manutenção e das correções pode ir até 100 vezes o custo da "criação". Sabemos também que, mesmo se nos gastamos muito tempo para "pensar em tudo", vai ter coisas que nós vamos modificar o "imaginar" durante o processo.
Então, devemos ter 2 objetivos:

1) tentar imaginar tudo. Por isso, UML pode ser bom. Ao mesmo tempo, eu prefiro colocar grande folhas de papel na parede e fazer desenho para ter uma visão global (low-tech!)

2) admitir (é o mais difícil!) que vamos ter que corrigir, porque somos programadores ruins.

Para prever o segundo ponto, se é para um projeto grande:

1) Evitar as bibliotecas sem demonstração que eles vão ter uma vida longa (da uma olhada nas "maravilhosas bibliotecas" dos anos passados.)

2) Definir uma "política" de nome de pastas, documentos, arquivos etc... Não tem solução "melhor" mas você precisa definir.

E como na ISO: você pode fazer do jeito que você quiser, mas precisa escrever como você vai fazer e depois, seguir o que foi escrito.

3) Ter documentação, mas isso depende do projeto.

No meu caso, tenho um doc com as tabelas, em ordem alfabética. Cada tabela tem um nome do tipo `TAB_CLIENTE` e os campos tem todos nome relativos a tabela. Por exemplo `tcliente_nom`.

E possível ter `TAB_CLIENTE.nome` mais como e possível ter também `TAB_VENDEDOR.nome`, quando você esta na frente de "nome" você não sabe se é o nome do vendedor ou de cliente.
Tem descrição de cada campo, uso, tipo de conteúdo.

Tenho também um doc com as funções das minhas bibliotecas.

Todo esta no papel. Eu faço no Word, com numero de versão. Quando tem uma modificação (o que acontece no mínimo uma vez por dia), eu faço a modificação no Word, mais ao invés de ré-imprimir tudo (a doc das tabelas tem 77 paginas!), impressão das modificações -> fita adesiva -> no documento "papel": pronto! Quando tem muitos modificações, precisa imprimir tudo de novo.

Eu iniciei faz um ano, estou fazendo no mesmo tempo este "site" e aplicativos Android (também com este tipo de doc).

Acho que o ponto chave e o seguinte: da um olhada na "área" da sua tela e na "área" da mesa. Devemos admitir que tentar usar somente a tela é uma brincadeira porque o espaço é pequeno. Então, precisa imprimir. Tenho um Epson M105 com tank de tinta.

- Cuidar de documentos é como cuidar de crianças. Para cuidar de 10 precisa de muito mais esforço que 10 vezes o esforço para cuidar de um.
- Um projeto e como correr na praia para ir nadar: o início vamos "lentamente" na areia seca, depois vamos acelerar muito na areia molhada. Mas, então, quanto mais avançamos na água, mais lentamente vamos. No inglês chamam isso de "diminishing return": quando eu faço 50% da segunda parte, eu faço somente 25% do total... Então, não hesite parar e documentar muito. Na primeira parte, será um desperdício de tempo, mas o ganho final será enorme.
- Colocar um monte de comentários no seu código. Eu fui 10 anos chefe de projeto com equipes de até 50 pessoas. Nosso descoberta foi que, mesmo com ferramentas "maravilhosas", o ponto principal é "os comentários". Para ter um código que você vai poder modificar sem problema depois de 1 ano, precisa de mais ou menos de 80 linhas de comentários para 100 linhas de código.

Se você esta interessado em "Software Quality", da uma olhada aqui: http://www.crosstalkonline.org/

Tem realmente um monte de coisa sobre qualidade.

Dê a sua opinião, porque nesta área, trocar ideia é muito bom!

Comment: corrigi alguns erros de concordância em sua resposta. Notei que o português não é sua língua nativa. Se alterei o sentido original de alguma parte favor editar novamente :)

Comment: @Peter, fujindo totalmente do assunto, este tipo Nomeclatura redudante e com prefixos desnecessarios para tabelas e colunas é triste... Serio, sempre que vejo alguem sugerir isto me dá calafrios... depois dá uma olhada na seguinte, que é proposta para o SQL Server 2005 pelo Steve Bates: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/steven_bates/archive/2006/03/20/database-object-naming-rules.aspx
Lembrando que é apenas um ponto de vista diferente, espero que seja uma leitura agradavel.

Comment: E verdade que TRGA_CustomerInsUpdDe e muito mas claro...

Comment: gmsantos, muito obrigado.