# Como escrever corretamente um documento de visão do projeto?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, engenharia-de-software, ddd, projeto-de-software, gerenciamento-de-projetos

Sou um desenvolvedor que trabalha sozinho e faz algum tempo [questionei aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53491/documenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-inicio-de-um-projeto-trabalhando-sozinho) sobre quais documentos realmente seriam importantes de serem produzidos no início do processo de desenvolvimento.

Analisando a resposta aceita, me pareceu claro que o *primeiro* documento que realmente precisa ser feito é o *documento de visão de projeto* que lá está descrito como:

> **Visão do projeto:** qual problema será resolvido e como será resolvido e qual o valor desta solução para o cliente. Isto é muito importante para manter o foco e não se distrair com o que não for prioridade nem desviar o projeto do seu objetivo principal. Este documento é muito curto e o simples ato de escrevê-lo, como eu disse, ajuda a aprofundar o entendimento do problema e da solução.

Combinando isso com as discussões apresentadas nas perguntas [Domain-Driven Design e levantamento de requisitos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90561/domain-driven-design-e-levantamento-de-requisitos) e [Como obter o conhecimento necessário sobre um domínio?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54759/como-obter-o-conhecimento-necess%C3%A1rio-sobre-um-dom%C3%ADnio) parece claro para mim que o documento de visão de projeto é extremamente importante, sendo ele inclusive o ponto de partida para a montagem do backlog e a organização e priorização do que precisa ser feito.

Tendo isso em vista, pesquisei um pouco sobre como escrever esse documento, o que deve estar contido nele, como seria a maneira ideal de estruturar e escrever esse conteúdo, enfim, como fazer *um bom e útil documento de visão*. Afinal, não basta sair escrevendo qualquer coisa, o que for produzido precisa ser realmente útil.

Cheguei a encontrar alguns modelos, um deles (que pode ser [baixado aqui](http://www.startupcto.com/templates/software-vision-document-template)) até me pareceu razoável, mas ele trata de questões até de interface de usuário, e não sei se é exatamente isso que se busca nesse documento.

Nesse contexto, minha pergunta é a seguinte: como escrever um documento de visão bom e realmente útil para o projeto? O que ele deve conter e como deve ser estruturado? Alguns pontos que pensei que devem estar contidos são: motivação para o software e problema a ser resolvido e atores que vão interagir com o software, mas certamente há outras informações necessárias.

Com quem devemos buscar as informações para a construção desse documento? No caso de o software ser feito a pedido de alguém, acredito que as informações devam partir do requerente, mas e se o software for ideia minha, eu que terei as informações para montar esse documento?

Enfim, em resumo, como se monta um documento de visão de projeto sucinto e útil?

**EDIT**: Em virtude dos votos para fechamento, acho que vale a pena esclarecer que não se busca resposta baseada em opiniões. Pelo que entendi nas outras perguntas que fiz a escrita desse documento é uma parte importante do processo de coleta de requisitos e, obviamente, existem jeitos de fazer que vão resultar em uma ferramenta útil para o desenvolvimento e jeitos de fazer que não vão agregar valor e só vão complicar a vida. O que diz como fazer da melhor forma, o que o documento deve conter e tudo mais, é a experiência. Nesse caso, o que eu procuro é uma resposta não baseada em opinião, mas em experiência, sendo a resposta objetiva da forma: "desse jeito já foi experimentado, já foi utilizado e deu certo".

Comment: Não é uma questão adequadamente classificada como **projeto-de-software**) (*software design*). Remover esta marca facilitará a localização de questões.

Comment: Sua pergunta fala em produto (software), projeto, processo de desenvolvimento. O documento que não pode deixar de existir em qualquer projeto é o termo de abertura do projeto e o WBS (ou EAP em português). Todos os demais vão depender da natureza do projeto. Adicionalmente, tendo em vista as dúvidas colocadas, não seria possível criar um documento de visão do produto, seria necessário um projeto para criar tal visão (registrada no documento visão do produto). O que me diz?

Answer (score -2):

Em minha humilde opinião, a forma mais simples é usar o método Socrático, ou seja:

O que?

Por que?

Como?

Onde?

O que não é?

Conclusão

Visão

Refletindo sobre estas questões você pode chegar à conclusão e dela à visão do projeto. Você pode mudar a ordem e acrescentar outras questões que ajudem a formar esta visão.